# Save output of each itertation and combine in one variable

Tags: matlab, loops, vectorization

I am getting a 2-column double array output from each iteration of a loop. Every time the result is 30×2 , 40×2 , 99×2, ... and so on.

I want to save the result of each iteration in the same variable, lets say in `data`.

Currently, every time the loop is running only the last output is saved.

What I want is to have all of the outputs stored in `data` like in the first 30 rows the first output, which is 30×2, and from row 31 to 71 the output from the second iteration which is 40×2 and so on.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please show a [mcve], and **look at the [many questions already about saving loop outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmatlab%5D+store+loop)**. This is very dependent on whether you know how many rows are going to be in the output each time - if not then use a cell array and combine at the end, otherwise just pre-allocate the large output array and assign sub-rows each loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try the following:

For the first iteration of the loop,
    data=result;

For subsequent iterations,
    data=[data; result];

Comment: **1.** Answering low quality questions (no [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), been [asked many times before](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmatlab%5D+store+loop)) can be unhelpful for the site. **2.** Please [format your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) in questions and answers.  **3.** You don't need iteration specific behaviour, setting `data=[]` before the loop would be enough. **4.** Arrays growing within loops is bad practise and relatively slow in MATLAB, see the linked answers for alternatives.

Comment: @Wolfie: Thanks for the feedback. (1) This question was very clear to me, even without example code, and it also could be unhelpful for the site to scare away new users by dinging them more than needed. (2) Agreed. (3) Great point! (4) Good point in general, but I did not see a way around this yet, for this particular question. I am researching the alternatives.

Comment: No worries... *For this particular question*, depends on further details which the OP didn't supply. If it's a `for` loop then you know the number of iterations, you can set up a cell array of the correct size (`c = cell(n,1)`), then after the loop concatenate all arrays using `a = vertcat(c{:})`. Alternatively knowing all of the array sizes up front you can create `a` before the loop. Anyway as I said before, I'm just rephrasing things already stated on the site.

Comment: Thank you @Wolfie your suggestion of correct cell array worked! plus the answer from Tom also helped! Secondly I would also agree with all the points from Tom! I am very new to the site I would learn with the time I hope.
Thank you!